# How can I use a keyword as a property name?

Tags: c#, json, anonymous-types

I have been serializing anonymous types into json quite successfully until now..

```
        dynamic jsObject;

        jsObject = new ExpandoObject();
        jsObject.dataUrl = Controller.Url.Action("loadall", "residuals", new { EditionId = EditionId, Country = Country, ModelYear = ModelYear, MakeId = ModelId, StyleId = style.Id });
        jsObject.id = style.Id;
        jsObject.text = style.Name;
        jsObject.iconCls = "sprite-toolbar-flag-us";
        jsObject.checked = false; // <---<< the problem is here
        jsObject.leaf = true;
        jsObject.IsCustomQuote = style.IsCustomQuote;

        return jsObject;
```

Is there a workaround?  I'm gonna try to serialize a dictionary into a json object if not..

Comment: Exactly which part is busted? `StyleId = style.Id`?

Comment: oh whoops, I overwrote my commented line that pointed out where the error was. hhehe I'll update the question.  sorry about that.  Also, thanks for the edit gabe.. I wasnt thinking clearly when I wrote that title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use the "verbatim" operator `@`: `jsObject.@checked = false;`